# performSegueWithIdentifier going to wrong view

Tags: objective-c, xcode4

I am using this code to make a tableview cell go to a new view:

`[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"hello" sender:self];`

But whenever I build and run it, and click on the cell, it brings me to a completely different/unrelated view.
Any ideas?

Comment: double check the identifier of your segue in storyboard?

Comment: Any chance you accidentally named two segues the same?

Answer (score 0):

Check the identifier of your segue in storyboard.

Also, if you have multiple segues, check that you have the correct segue connected to the correct button and the correct view.

Comment: I checked the identifier, and it is the same as the one called in the "performSegueWithIdentifier" line. How do I connect the segue to a specific button on the tableview? Right now I am just using the DidSelectRowAtIndexPath

Answer (score 0):

Try Following code in your TableViewController

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"yourSegueIdentifierName"]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        NSManagedObject *object = [[self fetchedResultsController] objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        [[segue destinationViewController] setDetailItem:object];
    }
}
```

This will listen for a segue, check for the identifier of the segue and the row you selected.  Then it performs your segue with the object at your selected row.
It also allows you to easily have multiple segues in one view if you would need it, you just have to add 'if' functions for different segue identifiers.

If you use only ONE segue in your TableViewController, you don't actually really need the identifier, but it is good practise to use it anyway, just in case you want to add some other segue to your code in a later stage.

Comment: Assuming I put it in the right place, it is riddled with errors even after i substitute the tableview names and such, where exactly should I put this?

Comment: You put this in the implemention file (.m) of your TableViewController window.  You don't need to change anything in the code, you can just copy-paste what I wrote, apart from the string that identifies your segue.  In Storyboard, you need to give your segue a name, and write exactly that name in the string where I put "yourSegueIdentifierName".    This code will hand over the details of the cell you clicked on to the next view, assuming that is what you want.  If you want a more detailed answer, you have to copy paste your code here, so I know exactly what you want..

Comment: Thanks for the reply, here is my code of the implementation file

http://pastebin.com/KDzHYfQV